# Microsoft Exchange Server 2016(Console) error: Server Error in '/ecp' Application

Tags: exchange-server, microsoft-exchange, exchange-server-2016

The ECP login page works but after a successful login we get following error. Any suggestions?

```
Server Error in '/ecp' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.   

Stack Trace: 



[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.FbaModule.ParseCadataCookies(HttpApplication httpApplication) +2272
   Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.FbaModule.OnBeginRequestInternal(HttpApplication httpApplication) +228
   Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<OnBeginRequest>b__0() +1681
   Microsoft.Exchange.Common.IL.ILUtil.DoTryFilterCatch(Action tryDelegate, Func`2 filterDelegate, Action`1 catchDelegate) +35
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +93

  


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4110.0
```

Running the command IISReset does not resolve the problem. The certificates seems to be ok.